# Nodejs mysql rest api query not executing

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to make a login/sign up API with nodejs, express and mysql.
When testing it i don't get any errors and i get the "Succesful Sign Up!" message. When i check the database though, the user table is still empty.

Here's the query i'm trying to execute.

```
con.query("INSERT INTO user (unique_id, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?,?,?,?,NOW(),NOW())",[uid, email, password, salt], function (err, result, fields) {
          con.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('[MySQL ERROR]',err);
            res.json('Resgister Error: ',err);
          });
          res.json('Succesful Sign Up!');
        })
```

And here's the full code.

```
//Libraries
var crypto = require('crypto');
var uuid = require('uuid');
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//connection with MySQL

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "user",
  password: "password",
  database: "database",
});

//Encrypting password

var genRandomString = function (length) {
  return crypto
    .randomBytes(Math.ceil(length / 2))
    .toString('hex')
    .slice(0, length);
};

var sha512 = function (password, salt) {
  var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', salt);
  hash.update(password);
  var value = hash.digest('hex');
  return {
    salt: salt,
    passwordHash: value,
  };
};

function saltHashPassword(userPassword) {
  var salt = genRandomString(16);
  var passwordData = sha512(userPassword, salt);
  return passwordData;
}

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//Sign up
app.post('/register/', (req, res, next) => {
  var post_data = req.body;

  var uid = uuid.v4();
  var plaint_password = post_data.password;
  var hash_data = saltHashPassword(plaint_password);
  var password = hash_data.passwordHash;
  var salt = hash_data.salt;

  var email = post_data.email;

  con.query("SELECT * FROM user where email=?", [email], function (err,result,fields) {
    con.on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('[MySQL ERROR]', err);
    });
    if (result && result.length) 
        res.json('User already exists');
    else
    {
      con.query("INSERT INTO user (unique_id, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?,?,?,?,NOW(),NOW())",[uid, email, password, salt], function (err, result, fields) {
          con.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('[MySQL ERROR]',err);
            res.json('Resgister Error: ',err);
          });
          res.json('Succesful Sign Up!');
        })
    }
  });
})

//Login
app.post('/login/', (req, res, next) =>{

  var post_data = req.body;

  var user_password = post_data.password;
  var email = post_data.email;

  con.query("SELECT * FROM user where email=?", [email], function (err,result,fields) {
    con.on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('[MySQL ERROR]', err);
    });
    if (result && result.length) 
        {
          var salt = result [0].salt;
          var encrypted_password = result[0].encrypted_password;
          var hashed_password = checkHashPassword(user_password,salt).passwordHash;
          if(encrypted_password==hashed_password)
          res.end(JSON.stringify(result[0]))
          else
          res.end(JSON.stringify('Wrong Credentials'))
        }
    else
    {
      res.json('Wrong Credentials')
    }
  });

})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("RESTFul API running in port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try this and let me know if it works

```
con.query("INSERT INTO user (unique_id, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (?,?,?,?,NOW(),NOW())",[uid, email, password, salt], function (err, result, fields) {
              if(err) {
                console.log('[MySQL ERROR]',err);
                res.json('Resgister Error: ',err);
              }else {

              res.json('Succesful Sign Up!');
              }
          })
```